# this is my code. I want my search engine to turn the results into links to another page. idk how to

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php

require_once 'db/connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

    $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

    $query = $db->query("
        SELECT title
        FROM articles
        WHERE body LIKE '%{$keywords}%' 
        OR title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
    ");
    ?>

    <div class="result-count">
        Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results
    </div>

    <?php

    if($query->num_rows) {
        while($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
        ?>
            <div class="result">
                <a href="#"><?php echo $r->title; ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the link where the # is

Comment: what if I have multiple links?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all you are querying for is the article title? if this is all you need for the url then just replace the

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $r->title; ?></a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $r->title; ?>"><?php echo $r->title; ?></a>
```

however if you need an id or something else then you will need to ensure your database query is returning that data for example

```
SELECT ID, Title FROM...
```

then use

```
<a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $r->id; ?>">...
```